# Facebook authentication with Passport JS using Node fails

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, facebook-authentication, passport-facebook

I have an issue with Facebook Strategy failing after successfully logging into Facebook. I'm using Passport Local and Passport Facebook, but independent of each other, here are the code what I have shared.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'XYZId',
    clientSecret: 'XYZSecret',
    callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      console.log(profile);
      userDetails = profile;
      return done();
  }
));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
     passport.authenticate('facebook', {
             failureRedirect: '/login' }),
             function(req, res) {
                    console.log("req");
                    console.log(userDetails);
                    console.log("End of Req");
                    res.redirect('/');
              });
```

Is there anything wrong in this code? Also, for local strategy I have modified a bit which is working perfectly fine.

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);
// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

// =========================================================================
// passport session setup ==================================================
// =========================================================================
// required for persistent login sessions
// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});

// =========================================================================
// LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

passport.use(
    'local-signup',
    new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) {
        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
            } else {
                // if there is no user with that username
                // create the user
                console.log(req.body);
                var newUserMysql = {
                    uname: req.body.uname,
                    username: username,
                    userphone: req.body.userphone,
                    password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)  // use the generateHash function in our user model
                };

                var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( uname, username, password, userphone ) values (?,?,?,?)";
                console.log(insertQuery);
                connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.uname, newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password, newUserMysql.userphone],function(err, rows) {
                    newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                    return done(null, newUserMysql);
                });
            }
        });
    })
);

// =========================================================================
// LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

passport.use(
    'local-login',
    new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows){
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (!rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
            }

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, rows[0]);
        });
    })
);
};
```

Console Log : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't store authorized facebook user in session. You just call function `done()` without parameters in the implementation of FacebookStrategy. First, you should store fb user in your database or select if exist then call function done (receives first param as error, second as user object). [here's docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook)

Comment: Thanks a ton Tilov.